# Why did Malfoy rip a page from a book in CoS?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

I was recently watching the movie *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*. 
In the beginning you can see Draco Malfoy ripping out a page from a book in the bookstore Flourish and Blotts.

**For what reason does he need this page?**

I've already heard some theories about helping Hermione and Ron 
with the basilisk but this sounds sort of implausible.

Could someone please explain this scene to me? AFAIK it has not been told in the books.

Note: I am searching for canon answers such as quotes from J.K. Rowling.

Comment: *Helping Ron and Hermione* doesn't really sound like the Malfoy I know.

Comment: Yes I know, therefore I want a canon answer from J.K Rowling if it exists.

Comment: If it's a scene exclusive to the movies, then J.K Rowling would be the last person able to answer it.

Comment: Since it is specifically about film canon (as you say, he doesn't do this in the book), shouldn't you be looking for quotes from the filmmakers instead of JKR? Is there any reason it couldn't have just been random acts of vandalism?

Comment: @BMWurm, ibid Good point. quotes from the filmmakers are also allowed. I thought J.K Rowling had influence on the films.

Comment: @user59360 she had influence but choose never to use it. (Even with regards to how "Voldemort" is pronounced.)

Comment: [Jeremy voice:] Director said, make this character rip a page off a book to make him look more like an a**hole.

Comment: I was more concerned about the fact that *Hermione* ripped a page from a library-book... (the page about the baselisk.)  Destruction of other people's property, seems to be quite in the character of Draco.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There is no canon answer to your question, or an answer from J.K. Rowling, but I feel safe in saying that Malfoy was likely just being a jerk. The last person Draco would assist in *any* manner would be Hermione -- heck, he wished her dead by the Basilisk in *Chamber of Secrets*. I don't believe, characterization wise, that Draco and Hermione had any sort of secret romance or revising club going on.

In book six, we see Draco being a jerk to Madam Malkin as she tried to fit him with new Hogwarts robes -- Draco and his mother end up huffing out of Madam Malkin's, after Draco just unceremoniously drops the robes on the floor. This is not a guy who is respectful of other peoples' property.

**Malfoy was being a jerk.**

Comment: Why "was", he *is* a jerk throughout the entire series. That is his main character trait, the main bully of Hogwarts.

Comment: Also, is there any evidence in the book of CoS that Malfoy tore a page from a book? Or is this exclusive to the movie?

Comment: @AdrianMann No evidence in the book :)

Comment: @Dawny33 I thought it may have been something added by JK to make the readers dislike Malfoy even more because as a book lover she would never vandalise a book and look down on others who do, big time! Like all of us.

Comment: @AdrianMann There was evidence in the book. Malfoy ripped it out. Now no one can prove he ripped it out of the book because he ripped out the evidence of him doing it, despite the fact it must have been written in the book before he did it so he could have just walked away and let the book be false. Time travel sucks.

Comment: @Thomas: At the conclusion of the entire series, there's some possibility that he is less of a jerk. He at least acknowledges Harry when they're all grown up. So "was" is pretty appropriate.

Comment: @Thomas - Neither *Why is Malfoy a jerk?* nor *Why was Malfoy a jerk* is the question being asked here. But it's a great question *Hint Hint Nod Nod*!

Comment: @Ellesedil - I agree with what you're saying, and thought it was nice/poignant that Malfoy did receive a certain redemption, but not a redemption that was like a pretty package tied up with a bow. :)

Answer (score 19):

Firstly, there is no evidence of that happening in the books. So, the director might just wanted to portray the traits and personality of the character, Malfoy better by showing him as a jerk.

In addition to Slytherincess' answer (which should be accepted IMO), it should be noted that **Malfoy loves to flaunt the fact that his family is one of the richest in the magic world.**

So, it would be a pleasure for him to see his father throwing away money at the shopkeeper for a very measly reason (for damage).

And, as Slytherincess have already put it nicely, he is just being a jerk, which he always was throughout the series.

Comment: I wonder if Lucius Malfoy would even bother paying for the damaged property, or if he'd just use his clout to ignore it entirely. Either way, I'm sure Draco would love it!

Comment: @BiscuitBaker Like father, like son :D